# Jquery UI dialog popup chaining: When closed the child popup parent popup is not focusing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I am using Jquery UI dialog for popups in my applications.
In one scenario I need a popup inside a popup.
And I am able to get the Child popup too. but when I close the the child popup parent popup is not getting focused. but when I increase the z index of parent by inspect, it is getting focused. So I found that when I close the child popup something is overlaying the parent popup.
Please help.

Thanks In advance...

Comment: Create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) with your code for a start.